# Angular custom directive has multiple problems - doesn't work with replace: true, doesn't trigger second time

Tags: angularjs, triggers, angular-directive

I have made a custom Angular directive like so:

HTML - `mydirective(data-datasource="mydirectivedata", data-updatefn="mydirectiveupdate")`

Controller -

```
$scope.mydirectivedata = //array of objects from API service call using $http
$scope.mydirectiveupdate = function(a, b) {}
```

Directive -

```
.directive('mydirective', function() {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    mydirectivedata: '=',
                    mydirectiveupdate: '&',
                },
                controller: function($scope) {
                    $scope.updatefunction = function(id, type) {
                        $scope.mydirectiveupdate()(id, type);
                    };
                },
                templateUrl: '/partials/mydirective.html'
            }
        })
```

Partial -

```
<li data-ng-repeat="type in datasource.types">
  <input id="{{type.id}}" type="radio" name="{{$parent.datasource.id}}" src="" alt="{{$parent.datasource.id}}" aria-label="type.name" checked ng-value="true" data-ng-class="radio-selector" data-ng-model="type.isDefault" data-ng-change="updatefunction($parent.datasource.id,type)">
  <label for="{{type.id}}"><span style="background-image: url(undefined)"></span>
    <h2 data-ng-bind="type.name">type.name</h2>
    <p data-ng-bind="{{type.price}} | number :2" class="price">{{type.price}}</p>
    <p data-ng-bind="type.description">type.description</p>
  </label>
</li>
```

My requirements are:
1. When the input radio button is selected, trigger the `updatefunction` and in turn the `mydirectiveupdate` function passing the required parameters

The issue is:
 1. If I use `replace: true` in my directive, the `$scope.updatefunction` itself isn't getting triggered
 2. If I don't use `replace: true`, the update function is getting triggered, but only once per input click. The second time an input is clicked, the function isn't triggered!

HELP!!

Comment: Suggest you make a working demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue). Some of the code shown doesn't match between scope properties and html attributes. Not to mention `alt` and `src` don't make sense for a radio either

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand second line of your post:

> HTML - `mydirective(data-datasource="mydirectivedata", data-updatefn="mydirectiveupdate")`

I guess that you mean something like:

```
<mydirective data-mydirectivedata="mydirectivedata" data-mydirectiveupdate="mydirectiveupdate" />
```

I also don't know what is

> Partial -

I assume that this is a template for your directive. If so, you cannot use `replace: true`, because you don't have parent DOM element. Put whole
`<li data-ng-repeat="type in datasource.types">...</li>` code inside `<ul>` tag.

Once you have datasource (this HTML and Partial) and once this is mydirectivedata (directive definition). Review your example taking all of this into account.